# Adding Message to MessageQueue programmatically

Tags: c#, msmq

I have the old 'non-transactional' queue (MessageQueue) which may have messages in it.

Now programatically, I want to:
1. Get the messages from old queue ----> this is done
2. Create new 'transactional' queue ---> this is also done
3. Copy messages from old message queue to new queue -----> **How to do this?**
4. Delete the old queue. --- > I can do it by calling Close(), then Dispose() for the old queue and the I can delete the queue using MessageQueue.Delete(). **Is it right? And is it necessary to call Close and Dispose before deleting the queue?**

Please guide me regarding questions in bold letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read the contents of message from old queue and `Send` it to new queue as new message. There is no Copy method.

To delete a queue, you can use static method, so the Close / Dispose does not apply:

`System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Delete(@"myMachine\MyQueue");`

Comment: This is exactly my question. How to post messages (taken from old queue) to newly created queue?

Comment: It depends whether you can use the original Structure that had been used to post to old queue. If so, i'd just fill the structure with what is in old queue and then send it to new one with `MessageQueue.Send`.

Comment: Your reply is helpful. However I am quite new to MSMQ. Will you please elaborate little or give me exact name of the method ?

Comment: If you don't, however, you can try reading binary contents of the messages (`BodyStream` property) and after that, create a `Message` object, fill the BodyStream and send using `Send`. However, there are some other properties along with Body, so if you want to preserve them, you must set them all as well.